# switching images in div. using javascript background-image: url(id="demo");

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the color of an arrow based on the value of a variable.  In div.f I am trying to change between two different image files to accomplish this. You can see the logic in the first var newq = temp();  call towards the bottom of the code.  I am sure it is just a syntax error, but I can't figure it out.

```js
//window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

$(document).ready(function() {
  animateDiv();

});

function blooddias() {
  var min = 245.5;
  var max = 260;
  var nw = 915;
  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return [nh, nw];
}

function bloodsyst() {
  var min = 255.5;
  var max = 269;
  var nw = 777;
  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return [nh, nw];
}

function cellrate() {
  var min = 255.5;
  var max = 269;
  var nw = 640;
  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return [nh, nw];
}

function lungs() {
  var min = 255.5;
  var max = 269;
  var nw = 355;
  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return [nh, nw];
}

function brain() {
  var min = 255.5;
  var max = 269;
  var nw = 225;
  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return [nh, nw];
}

function temp() {
  var min = 185;
  var max = 219;
  //var nh = 200;
  var nw = 85;
  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv() {

  var newq = blooddias();
  $('.a').animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, function() {
    animateDiv();
  });
  var newq = bloodsyst();
  $('.b').animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, function() {
    animateDiv();
  });
  var newq = cellrate();
  $('.c').animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, function() {
    animateDiv();
  });
  var newq = lungs();
  $('.d').animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, function() {
    animateDiv();
  });
  var newq = brain();
  $('.e').animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, function() {
    animateDiv();
  });
  var newq = temp();
  if (newq[0] > 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "redarrow";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "orangearrow";
  }

  var newq = temp();
  $('.f').animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, function() {
    animateDiv();
  });
};
```

```css
div.a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("greenarrow.png");
  position: fixed;
}

div.b {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("greenarrow.png");
  position: fixed;
}

div.c {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("greenarrow.png");
  position: fixed;
}

div.d {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("greenarrow.png");
  position: fixed;
}

div.e {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("greenarrow.png");
  position: fixed;
}

div.f {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("id=demo.png");
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.js"></script>

<body background="startrekbg.png">

  <div class='a'></div>
  <div class='b'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='d'></div>
  <div class='e'></div>
  <div class='f'></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: call to undefined function `require('jquery')` ??? requirejs ???

Comment: i updated the code watch it an tell me, you are missing the `#demo`  `div` in the code i added it my self

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam thanks for your input.  I should change background-image: url("id=demo.png");  to background-image: url(#idemo div);

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam ,   For some reason,  url("id=demo.png"); still will not load image file.

Comment: that is not the correct way to do it `background-image:url()` can contain only path css cannot evaluate your expression id=demo.png, i cant understand what are you trying to do

Comment: Trying to switch between image files:

}div.f {
 width: 50px;
 height:50px;
  background-image: url(id=demo);  
 position:fixed;
 }

<div id='demo'></div>

var newq = temp();
    if(newq[0] > 200){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="redarrow.png";
    }else{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="orangearrow.png";
    }

Comment: I believe that you are trying to change background-image of "div.f". With that understanding, try as below:

var imgPath = "/your/path";
$(".f").css("backgroundImage", imgPath);

Comment: @Vinay Gayakwad ,  Thanks, that is correct.  It is a thermometer and different color arrows are used to denote temperature level.  So put this code between <script>...</script>?  The $ makes me think it is javascript code.

Comment: Yes, it is javascript/Jquery code. You have to add these lines in the condition where you are trying to change background-image.

Comment: @ Vinay Gayakwad ,  Sorry, can't get it to work.  From what I can tell by searching for two days, getting a variable in url(" ");  seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to manipulate the HTML paths.  Decide to see if I could make the HTML invisible.  Luckily there is a JavaScript feature called "opacity" that allows you to hide images when they are not needed.  As seen here:
var newq = temp();

```
if(newq[0]<200){  //border between organge and red
var c = 0;
var t = 100;
}else{
var t = 0;
var c = 100;
     }
$('.f').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1], opacity:c },
function(){
});
$('.g').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1], opacity:t }, 
function(){
animateDiv();//Recursive call
});
```